# Footer div won't stick to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, position, footer

I'd like to have a footer div that sticks to the bottom (and left and right) of the page. However, my footer div doesn't go all the way down and left. How can I fix this? (no "position: fixed;")

Here's my code: (I changed all the text to dots, the footer div is the last div in the code.

```css
body {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
 position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 right: 0px;
 left: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #262626;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color:white;
}

li img {
 padding-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #262626;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4d4d4d;
       color: white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #262626;
 font-family: proxima-nova, "Proxima Nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 45px;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 margin-top: 88px;
}

h4 {
 position: relative;
 left: 100px;
 text-align: left;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 16 px;
 letter-spacing: 0.8px;
 line-height: 34px;
 background-color: transparent;
 word-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.albumcovers {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.audio1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 left: 320px;
 bottom: 342px;
}

.audio2 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 right: 186px;
 bottom: 307px;
}

.audio3 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 left: 320px;
 bottom: 316px;
}

.audio4 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 right: 186px;
 bottom: 281px;
}

.audio5 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 left: 320px;
 bottom: 290px;
}

.audio6 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 right: 186px;
 bottom: 255px;
}

.audio7 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 left: 320px;
 bottom: 264px;
}

.audio8 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 right: 186px;
 bottom: 229px;
}

.audio9 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 left: 320px;
 bottom: 238px;
}

.audio10 {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 right: 186px;
 bottom: 203px;
}

.dec1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #cccccc;
 font-size: 16px;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
 word-spacing: 150px;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 7px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  .
 </title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300|Varela" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PlaylistReggae.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="hiphop.html"><img src="hiphop.png" alt="HIPHOP" style="width:120px;height:18px;"></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">.</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Reggae.html">.</a>
      <a href="OldSchool.html">.</a>
      <a href="Modern.html">.</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">.</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="PlaylistReggae.html">.</a>
      <a href="PlaylistOldSchool.html">.</a>
      <a href="PlaylistModern.html">.</a>
   <a href="* Nog in te vullen *">.</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">.</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">.</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>.</h1>

<div class="dec1">
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
</div>

<img class="albumcovers" src="albumreggae.png" alt="Reggae Album Covers" style="width:315px;height:317px;">

<h4>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>
 <div>.</div>

<audio controls class="audio1">
  <source src="TLB.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio2">
  <source src="CTD.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio3">
  <source src="ITL.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio4">
  <source src="BFS.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio5">
  <source src="SWT.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio6">
  <source src="CDP.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio7">
  <source src="MDR.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio8">
  <source src="WIV.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio9">
  <source src="NRS.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls class="audio10">
  <source src="MMD.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div class="footer">This is the footer.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no "position: fixed;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your missing the closing H4 tag.  So the browser implicitly adds it right before the closing body tag, which is after the footer.  By placing the closing H4 tag before the footer, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I just couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Didn't even see that.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer div inside the h4 tag. You need to close h4 before footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your HTML structure from template with 3 areas: `header`, `main` & `footer` and use the flex model to easily fix(push) your footer at the bottom .

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
/* layout */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background:tomato;
}
/* demo , show main scrolling*/

main:after {
  content: ' end';
}
main:hover:after {  
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>stuff that comes in header. Any height</header>
<main>content that comes here, ican overflow </main>
<footer>fonter at view. Any height</footer>
```

If you do not want `header` to be fixed, insert it inside `main`, it will scroll up with the rest of `main` content;